# How to return X and Y coordinates when using jquery.hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, hammer.js

I am programming a little page using jquery.hammer.js and I have having problems getting the x and y coordinates of a touch event.

my code is as follows:

```
var x1, y1;
var element = document.getElementById("myDIV")
$(element).hammer().on("touch", function(e){
x1 = e.clientX
y1 = e.clientY

document.getElementById("resultDIV").innerHTML = x1 + " " + y1
}
```

but all I get is "undefined undefined" as my result.

i have everything i can think of, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: try e.target.clientX, because e is even not the element, and event.tartget returns the element on which the event occurred.
https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started and search "Event Data", you will find all the properties of even

Comment: @AmitChotaliya thankyou but this didn't work either. I also saw this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416830/jquery-access-x-and-y-coordinates-custom-event) but nothing there helped either

Comment: @DFania Did you found the solution? I'm also stuck at the same problem.

Answer (score 12):

`e.gesture` is deprecated now.
With the latest version of Hammer.js, you should use

```
var tapX, tapY;
tapX = e.center.x;
tapY = e.center.y;
```

Comment: FYI, these give you page relevant coordinates, not object relative.

Comment: and how to get object relevant coordinate ?

Comment: For object relative try: e.changedPointers[0].pageX and e.changedPointers[0].pageY.

Comment: this isn't working for me on mobile... it seems like it has something to do with the page zoom, i'm getting x,y coordinates which look like around 1/2 what they should be, but there is *no* indication anywhere in the event structure of this (for instance, "scale" is reported as 1)

Answer (score 8):

1. You've missed `);` at the end.
2. Try to always use semicolons (`;`) in the end of each `statement`.
3. If you're starting to use some library, read the documentation and how-to section first.

You can find the information you want from the [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started#event-data).

**Update:**
I've analyzed the `event` object and found the `gesture` property of this object. The `gesture` contains another property, which is called `center`. And finally you can get the X and Y coordinates from this property by using `pageX` and `pageY`.

```
var x1, y1;
x1 = e.gesture.center.pageX;
y1 = e.gesture.center.pageY;
```

Here is the working demo of your example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qqx5/).

And also if you use `multi-touch`, you can get the coordinates of each touch by using the `touches` array of `gesture` property. The other property names remain the same (`pageX, pageY`).

```
var x1, y1;
x1 = e.gesture.touches[0].pageX;
y1 = e.gesture.touches[0].pageY;
```

Here is the [second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7qqx5/1/) of your example using `touches` array to get coordinates for only the first touch.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to look into the original event to get mine working. Here is an example for anyone else with a similar situation.

```
$("#id").hammer({ domEvents: true }).on("press", ".elems", function (e) {
    console.log("pressed");
    console.log(e.originalEvent.gesture.center.x);
    console.log(e.originalEvent.gesture.center.y);
    return false;
});
```

Hammer version `Hammer.JS - v2.0.4 - 2014-09-28`

Answer (score 0):

in hammerjs `2.0.8` I use `ev.srcEvent.offsetX` and `ev.srcEvent.offsetY`